# How to understand the pointer star * in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I'm struggling with the pointer sign *, I find it very confusing in how it's used in both declarations and expressions.

For example:

```
int *i; // i is a pointer to an int
```

But what is the logic behind the syntax? What does the * just before the i mean? Let's take the following example. Please correct me where I'm wrong:

```
char **s;
char *(*s); // added parentheses to highlight precedence
```

And this is where I lose track. The *s between the parantheses means: s is a pointer? But a pointer to what? And what does the * outside the parentheses mean: a pointer to what s is pointing?

So the meaning of this is: The pointer pointing to what s is pointing is a pointer to a char?

I'm at a loss. Is the * sign interpreted differently in declarations and expressions? If so, how is it interpreted differently? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The rule of declaration in c is, you declare it the way you use it.

`char *p` means you need `*p` to get the char,

`char **p` means you need `**p` to get the char.

Answer (score 83):

Take it this way:

`int *i` means the value to which i points is an integer.

`char **p` means that p is a pointer which is itself a pointer to a char.[image]

Answer (score 80):

```
int i; //i is an int.
int *i; //i is a pointer to an int
int **i;//i is a pointer to a pointer to an int.
```

> Is the * sign interpreted differently in declarations and expressions?

Yes. They're completely different. in a declaration * is used to declare pointers. In an expression unary * is used to dereference a pointer (or as the binary multiplication operator)

Some examples:

```
int i = 10; //i is an int, it has allocated storage to store an int.
int *k; // k is an uninitialized pointer to an int. 
        //It does not store an int, but a pointer to one.
k = &i; // make k point to i. We take the address of i and store it in k
int j = *k; //here we dereference the k pointer to get at the int value it points
            //to. As it points to i, *k will get the value 10 and store it in j
```

Answer (score 22):

Declarations in C are expression-centric, meaning that the form of the declaration should match the form of the expression in executable code.

For example, suppose we have a pointer to an integer named `p`.  We want to access the integer value pointed to by `p`, so we *dereference* the pointer, like so:

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`; therefore, the declaration of `p` takes the form

```
int *p;
```

In this declaration, `int` is the *type specifier*, and `*p` is the *declarator*.  The declarator introduces the name of the object being declared (`p`), along with additional type information not provided by the type specifier.  In this case, the additional type information is that `p` is a pointer type.  The declaration can be read as either "`p` is of type pointer to `int`" or "`p` is a pointer to type `int`".  I prefer to use the second form, others prefer the first.

It's an accident of C and C++ syntax that you can write that declaration as either `int *p;` or `int* p;`.  In both cases, it's parsed as `int (*p);` -- in other words, the `*` is always associated with the variable name, not the type specifier.

Now suppose we have an array of pointers to `int`, and we want to access the value pointed to by the i'th element of the array.  We subscript into the array and dereference the result, like so:

```
x = *ap[i]; // parsed as *(ap[i]), since subscript has higher precedence
            // than dereference.
```

Again, the type of the *expression* `*ap[i]` is `int`, so the declaration of `ap` is

```
int *ap[N];
```

where the declarator `*ap[N]` signifies that `ap` is an array of pointers to `int`.

And just to drive the point home, now suppose we have a pointer to a pointer to `int` and want to access that value.  Again, we deference the pointer, then we dereference that result to get at the integer value:

```
x = **pp; // *pp deferences pp, then **pp dereferences the result of *pp
```

Since the type of the expression `**pp` is `int`, the declaration is

```
int **pp;
```

The declarator `**pp` indicates that `pp` is a pointer to another pointer to an `int`.

Double indirection shows up a lot, typically when you want to modify a pointer value you're passing to a function, such as:

```
void openAndInit(FILE **p)
{
  *p = fopen("AFile.txt", "r");
  // do other stuff
}

int main(void)
{
  FILE *f = NULL;
  ...
  openAndInit(&f);
  ...
}
```

In this case, we want the function to update the value of `f`; in order to do that, we must pass a pointer to `f`.  Since `f` is already a pointer type (`FILE *`), that means we are passing a pointer to a `FILE *`, hence the declaration of `p` as `FILE **p`.  Remember that the *expression* `*p` in `openAndInit` refers to the same object that the expression `f` in `main` does.

In both declarations and expressions, both `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`. For example, `*ap[i]` is interpreted as `*(ap[i])`; the expression `ap[i]` is a pointer type, and the `*` dereferences that pointer.  Thus `ap` is an *array of pointers*.  If you want to declare a *pointer to an array*, you must explicitly group the `*` with the array name, like so:

```
int (*pa)[N]; // pa is a pointer to an N-element array of int
```

and when you want to access a value in the array, you must deference `pa` before applying the subscript:

```
x = (*pa)[i];
```

Similarly with functions:

```
int *f(); // f is a function that returns a pointer to int
...
x = *f(); // we must dereference the result of f() to get the int value

int (*f)(); // f is a pointer to a function that returns an int
...
x = (*f)(); // we must dereference f and execute the result to get the int value
```

Answer (score 14):

My favorite method to parse complicated declarators is the [clockwise-spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Basically you start from the identifier and follow a clockwise spiral. See the link to learn exactly how it's used.

Two things the article doesn't mention:

1- You should separate the type specifier (int, char, etc.) from the declarator, parse the declarator and then add the type specifier.

2- If you encounter square brackets which denote an array, make sure you read the following square brackets (if there are any) as well.

Comment: could you give examples to your 1 and 2? with readouts? would be nice addition

Comment: Note that if you want to call that rule "clockwise" you also have to remember to go upwards from the name or you get incorrect results.

Answer (score 6):

`int * i` means i is a pointer to int (read backwards, read * as pointer).
`char **p` and `char *(*p)` both mean a pointer to a pointer to char.

Here's some other examples

`int* a[3]` // a is an array of 3 pointers to int

`int (*a)[3]` //a is a pointer to an array of 3 ints

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer in your questions.

Indeed a double star is used to indicate pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The * in declaration means that the variable is a pointer to some other variable / constant. meaning it can hold the address of variable of the type. for example: `char *c;` means that c can hold the address to some char, while `int *b` means b can hold the address of some int, the type of the reference is important, since in pointers arithmetic, `pointer + 1` is actually `pointer + (1 * sizeof(*pointer))`.

The * in expression means "the value stored in the address" so if `c` is a pointer to some char, then `*c` is the specific char.

`char *(*s);` meaning that s is a pointer to a pointer to char, so s doesn't hold the address of a char, but the address of variable that hold the address of a char.

Answer (score 1):

here is a bit of information

```
         variable    pointer
declaring     &a           p

reading/      a            *p

processing
```

Answer (score -2):

Declaring  `&a` means it points to `*i`. After all it is a pointer to `*int`. An integer is to point `*i`. But if consider `j = *k` is the pointer to the pointer this, means `&k` will be the value of `k` and `k` will have pointer to `*int`.