# Copy of address in C?

Tags: c

I know that this code:

```
void incVar(int i){
  i++; 
}
```

We know this will **create a copy** of the integer and then increase that value, but **not the actual value.**

**By nature:** Methods in **C** create copies of parameters in their Stack Frame and not the original variable.

But:

```
 void incVar(int *i){
      (*i)++; 
    }
```

Is supposed to increase the **actual value** of the integer by the pointer dereference.

But then, why doesn't **C** just create a copy of the pointer `*i` instead? If this is the normal behavior with regular integers, then why doesn't the same thing happen with pointers?

Comment: You did not change `i` so that conclusion just comes out of nowhere.

Comment: It is a common mistake to mix up a pointer declaration `int *i` with the pointer de-reference operator `*i`. Stupidly, the C language uses the `*` symbol for many completely different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand the pointer star \* in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484624/how-to-understand-the-pointer-star-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same with pointers. All variables in C are passed by value, even pointers.

You copy the address stored in the pointer outside the function, into its parameter.

But you can use that address to *reference* a variable which can be allocated anywhere. So in the following code:

```
int j = 0;
incVar(&j);
```

`incVar` receives *by-copy* the address of `j`. But it can use that address to read or modify `j` (in)directly.

Comment: I understand. Thanks! So if I have my first method, the address of the copied `x` is different from the global  `x` I defined?

Comment: @Amad27 - You mean `i`? Yes, its address is different from the address of the variable that was copied into it. In fact, all valid objects in C have a unique address at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the same thing as with values happens with pointers. Just make sure to understand the syntax correctly. You are *not* passing the integer `*i` by copy to `incVar`, but you are passing the pointer `i` of type `int*` by copy. No matter how often you copy the pointer to an address, it always points to the same address. So `i` in your second `incVar` example points to the integer the caller took the address of. So by derefencing the copy of the pointer (in `(*i)++`), you are acessing the integer of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to see `int *i;` as a variable named `i` of type *pointer-to-int*, instead of a pointer named `*i`.

In your example:

```
 void incVar(int *i) {
      (*i)++; 
    }
```

We probably use it as such in the main function:

```
int a = 5;
incVar(&a); //After this line, a is now 6.
```

What happens in `incVar(..)` is this:

1. A variable `i` is created, of type *pointer-to-int*.
2. It holds a **copy** of the value of `&a`.
3. Although `i` is a copy, its value is the same as that of the value of `&a`, and it still points to the same integer `a`.
4. As a result, by de-referencing `i`, I refer to the integer `a`.
5. Increment the integer `a`, which obviously is at the address pointed to by `i`.