# How can I assign the value to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I was studying the data structure in C programming.
and I got a question of pointer.
there is a simple initialization of pointer variable head.

```
int* head = NULL;
```

I had to look into the notion of pointer in C. and now I got it.
but,

when I use that code.
I can't understand how *head could be assigned by a value NULL.
because as I know, variable head(not *head) should have an int value first. (which is an address for type integer).

But It doesn't have any value in that code.

So... my opinion is.....

```
int* head;
head = (some address here);
*head = NULL;
```

this code does make sense to me. Because There is a value for head which has to be an address of type integer.

but still don't know how first code can work.

the first code:

```
int* head = NULL;
```

Comment: `NULL` can also be a pointer to an integer. `0` as an integer can be assigned to a pointer. By convention it is an address that points no where.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5484624/694576

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I didn't know this thing. really new. thanks.

Comment: @alk that question is very helpful to understand * :) thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say

```
int *head;
```

the name of the variable you are defining is `head`, and its type is "pointer to `int`", or `int *`.

When you say

```
int *head = NULL;
```

you're declaring the same variable `head`, and you're also giving it an initial value of `NULL`.

But since the name of the variable is `head`, if you want to define it on one line and then give it a value on a second line, do it like this:

```
int *head;
head = NULL;
```

But, it's true, this can be confusing at first.

For ordinary variables, you can easily imagine saying

```
int i = 5;
```

but then later changing it to

```
int i;
i = 5;
```

So if you say

```
int *head = NULL;
```

it's natural to want to change it to

```
int *head;
*head = NULL;
```

But this is wrong.

A big part of the confusion is that the `*` character ends up
doing two different things.

When you say

```
int *head;
```

what the `*` is doing is saying that you're declaring a pointer.
You're saying, "I'm declaring a variable named `head`, and it's a
pointer, and what it points to is `int`."

But when you say

```
*head = NULL;
```

what the `*` is doing is saying "Take the pointer `head`, and figure out
what it points to, and set the pointed-to location to `NULL`."

So when you say `*head = NULL`, you are *not* setting `head` to
`NULL`; you are setting the pointed-to location to NULL.  And
that's a very different thing.

Bottom line:  What you want here is

```
head = NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int* head = NULL;
```

in a function is equivalent to:

```
int* head;
head = NULL;    // Assign pointer value, *not* dereference
```

It is **not** equivalent to this (which would obviously be problematic because what would `head` point to?)

```
int* head;
*head = NULL;  // Dereference
```

Comment: "*... not equivalent to this*", because in this latter context the `*` acts as the "de-referring"-operator. Which made `*head` evaluate to an `int`, an `int` where `head` was pointing to, which it doesn't because it points to `NULL`, which is not a valid memory.

Comment: In function context, it's undefined behavior because `head` was never initialized.

Answer (score 1):

`int* head = NULL;` just means that head is a null pointer. NULL is just a macro for 0, and we've decided that a pointer with a value of 0 is pointing to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`int* header = NULL;` works fine until you try to access the value stored at the address `NULL` which will throw an error.

Pointers are addresses, you can declare an address without specifying if any value is present at that address.

I think what is misleading you is `NULL`.
`NULL` is used for pointers, not for effective values.

Comment: "*or addresses*" which addresses?

Comment: "*is used for pointers [...], not for effective values.*" a pointer is a variable just as any other in C. So a pointer also has a "value", like any other variable.

Comment: Ok maybe my explanation is a bit confusing. Pointers are used to store values, like any other variables, but those values are addresses in memory.

Comment: Ah well ok, still nitpicking: the pointer isn't the address, the pointer is a variable holding an address value. I'd consider the "address" itself being somewhere in the "hardware".

Comment: "*maybe my explanation*" so why not adjust it? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int* head = NULL;
```

Here you are defining a variable head of type `int *`. The assignment of `NULL` is to head itself, which means head is pointing to location `0`. It is a common way of indicating that head has not yet got a valid value.

Using `*head` is a different thing altogether though the confusion is understandable.

Comment: "*... head has not yet got a valid value.*" well, `NULL` **is** a valid value for a pointer. Still is it not addressing valid memory.

Comment: Also `NULL` not necessarily needs to refer to the physical address `0`. Although on many systems it does. Still,  if converted to an `int` it *always* evaluates to `0`.